# Como atualizar um Label automaticamente a cada minuto?

Tags: javafx

Estou querendo fazer uma aplicação que verifica o preço de um produto a cada minuto.

No meu Código teste esta da seguinte maneira:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import static sample.Controller.updateTicker;


public class MyTask{

    public Label helloWorld;

    public void criarTimer(Stage primaryStage) {
        int segundos = 10;
        int segundosParaComecar = 0;
        int segundosParaCapturar = segundos*1000;

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                helloWorld.setText(updateTicker());
            }
        };        

        timer.schedule(timerTask, segundosParaComecar, segundosParaCapturar);
    }
}
```

Mas estou tendo o seguinte log de Erro e não sei como resolver:

> Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException  at
>   sample.MyTask$1.run(MyTask.java:23)   at
>   java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)    at
>   java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

E erro ocorre quando vai setar a nova String na Label. O método `updateTicker()` esta retornando a String como esperado.

Comment: O `public Label helloWorld` está sendo instanciado e você está atribuindo uma referência à instância de `MyTask` quando a instancia? Tem cara de ser essa a variável que está nula.

Comment: Ela é instanciada assim que carrego meu `FXML`. Quando a Acesso em qual quer outra classe não tenho esse erro. Só quando coloco ela dentro do Método `run()`

Comment: Pode ser que o timer seja instanciado antes da carga do FXML? Tente pôr no `run()` `if (helloWorld != null) helloWorld.setText(updateTicker());`

Comment: Realmente estava nulo, Alterei o momento que chamo meu Metodo `criarTask()` e funcionou. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não misture awt com JavaFX.

Anote com `@FXML` tudo que for elemento do arquivo `.fxml`.

Utilize `Timer` e `TimerTask` para processos que não alteram os controles na UI, por exemplo, alguma ação que deve ser executada em *background* enquanto o programa está em execução.

Utilize as classes do pacote `javafx.animation.*` para tratar de alterar elementos na UI durante a execução da aplicação, que é o seu caso. Existe, por exemplo, a classe [`Timeline`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/Timeline.html) que serve justamente para este propósito.

```java
Timeline oneMinuteTimeline = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.minutes(1), event -> {
   helloWorld.setText(updateTicker());
}));

oneMinuteTimeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE); // Executar indefinidamente.
oneMinuteTimeline.play();
```

Isso irá alterar o valor do label `helloworld` a cada um minuto.

Criei um pequeno [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/reebr/18666ce7bef52fb5144b20bd79248746) de exemplo, atualizando um `Label` a cada um segundo. O resultado é este:

<kbd>[image: update label]</kbd>